# Capturing OS X media key events in Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, key-events

Does Firefox provide an API for extensions to capture media key events on OS X? These are physically located on the F7/F8/F9 keys on Apple's keyboards, but they don't have keycodes, so it seems impossible to intercept a media key press event with an `onkeypress` event.

To clarify: I have tried multiple JS tools which detect keycodes on `onkeypress` events. I can say with 100% confidence that the OS X media keys do not send an `onkeypress` event on any popular in-browser JS implementation unless the `fn` key is held down at the same time, but that isn't what I'm asking about.

To my understanding, Chrome implements a separate API which allows for capturing media key press events. I am asking if Firefox provides a similar API.

Comment: Go to this page, click in the textbox and try pressing the keys, it should tell you its keycode :) http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes if thats not it i dont understand the question totally, can you please elaborate, with pictures maybe

Comment: @Noitidart I've tried a number of those pages before asking, and (as explained on other pages I've researched), the OS X media keys apparently don't actually send an `onkeypress` event of any kind; they don't have a key/char code.

Comment: Can you show me what keys to push with an image im sure i can find a solution. And try keydown/keyup for some keys keycode doesnt go to keypress but does to keyup.

Comment: @Noitidart [Here's](http://imgur.com/vOZKCE3) an image showing the location of the keys. The act as normal function keys when holding down the `fn` button and send out key codes then, but when `fn` is being held down, they don't control media.

Comment: This works for me: `window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log('keycode pressed:', e.key, e.keyCode, e.charCode, e);
},false)` it logs to console: `keycode pressed: F12 123 0 keyup { target: <body>, key: "F12", charCode: 0, keyCode: 123 }`

Comment: @Noitidart and this works for you when pressing the media keys on an OS X keyboard, without holding down `fn`? Because it doesn't seem to be working for me for those specific keys.

Comment: I am using a virtualbox setup and a windows keyboard. So I cant replicate it exactly.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Wherever I like it seems people are using F keys, in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/hotkeys

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet. Hotkeys don't seem like they'd solve this problem.

Comment: I think ill get a chance to get on a real mac within the next month, Ill update you on if i get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Function keys do have keycodes. I guess you are talking about something like `Fn + F7/F8/F9`? You could intercept a multiple key combo for this. But this can get pretty messy.

See [this](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) and [this](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.fr/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html) for the gory details.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in capturing the media keypress events without holding down `Fn`, that's the part that doesn't seem possible in FF (at least, on OS X. Windows FF allows you to, and so does Chrome on OS X, apparently).

Answer (score 0):

This addon here says it supports osx media keys: https://github.com/mikedeboer/soundcloud-player

Quote:

> - Support for OSX media keys and Apple Remote - thanks to Markus Stange!
>
>   - Check out his project at https://github.com/mstange/mediakeysappleremotesimfy

You might find this topic interesting: https://github.com/mstange/mediakeysappleremotesimfy/issues/1

I posted there some objective c to get keycode of the keys pressed. So you can either:

1. Land solution right now, by using that js-ctypes, put it into a chromeworker, and have it send message to your mainthread on every time it detects a media key.
2. Wait for webextensions api to land the media command support